# What gets compared to what in the cmovl opcode?

Tags: assembly, compare

In the assembly opcode cmovl, what gets compared?
For example:
    EAX: 00000002
    EBX: 00000001

```
cmovl eax,ebx
```

What is the result? Which one needs to be less so they can be moved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

cmov doesn't do a comparison, it uses the result of a previous comparison - if it is true, it will perform the mov.  cmovl means "perform move if previous comparison resulted in "less than".

For example:

```
cmp ecx, 5
cmovl eax, ebx ; eax = ebx if ecx < 5
```

Comment: For beginners: Note 1: `cmovl` responds to flags in the flag register. In particular, it performs a move if `SF!=OF`, as Michael Burr pointed out in another answer. Note 2: `;` begins a comment in most assembly languages.

Answer (score 5):

It should be preceded by another instruction that sets flags appropriately, like `cmp`.

```
cmp ebx, ecx   ; compare ebx to ecx and set flags.
cmovl ebx, eax ; if (ebx < ecx (comparison based on flags)) ebx = eax
```

Answer (score 3):

`cmovl` will perform the move if the flags register has the following: `SF!=OF`

Those flags would be set as the result of some previous operation (typically, but not necessarily,  a compare of some sort).

The `cmovl` instruction does not perform a compare of its own.

Answer (score 1):

In AT&T assembly the equivalent code would be:

```
cmp   %ebx, %eax
cmovl %ebx, %eax
```

which would copy the value of `%ebx` to `%eax`, if the value held in `%eax` was greater than the value held in `%ebx` at the time of the `cmp` call.

With your example values, the result would be that the conditional move would not copy the value from `%ebx` to `%eax`, as `0x02` is clearly greater than `0x01`.